# AngularJS - why "Error: ng:areq Bad Argument"?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, autocomplete, angularjs-scope

I am trying to follow [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/sebmade/swfjT/) but all I got is

```
Error: ng:areq
Bad Argument
Argument 'DefaultCtrl' is not a function, got undefined
```

Can anyone tell exactly why? DefaultCtrl is there, why it is not seen?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.0.6/angular-material.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.0.6/angular-material.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function DefaultCtrl($scope) {
            $scope.names = ["john", "bill", "charlie", "robert", "alban", "oscar", "marie", "celine", "brad", "drew", "rebecca", "michel", "francis", "jean", "paul", "pierre", "nicolas", "alfred", "gerard", "louis", "albert", "edouard", "benoit", "guillaume", "nicolas", "joseph"];
        }

        angular.module('app', []).directive('autoComplete', function($timeout) {
            return function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
                    iElement.autocomplete({
                        source: scope[iAttrs.uiItems],
                        select: function() {
                            $timeout(function() {
                              iElement.trigger('input');
                            }, 0);
                        }
                    });
            };
        });
    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <form method=post>
    <div ng-app='app' >
        <div ng-controller='DefaultCtrl'>
            <input auto-complete ui-items="names" ng-model="selected">
            selected = {{selected}}
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type=submit>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i loved your first introduction - f*** true story...and there is no controller defined

Comment: The example uses a very old version of Angular. You might be better off reading current documentation because that style of declaring a controller is no longer allowed.

Comment: Jesus, that version of Angular is from 2012 - you weren't kidding about it being out of date...

Answer (score 0):

you need to define an angular controller this way:

```
angular.module("app", []).controller("DefaultCtrl", function(){
  //your stuff

});
```

the reason is:

You can imagine, that "angular" is just an javascript object representing your application - so if you want your application to know your controller, you have to add it (just the way i posted).

Answer (score 0):

You have to register your controller as part of your module.

```
function DefaultCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.names = ["john", "bill", "charlie", "robert", "alban", "oscar", "marie", "celine", "brad", "drew", "rebecca", "michel", "francis", "jean", "paul", "pierre", "nicolas", "alfred", "gerard", "louis", "albert", "edouard", "benoit", "guillaume", "nicolas", "joseph"];
}

angular.module('app', [])
    .controller("DefaultCtrl", DefaultCtrl)
    .directive('autoComplete', function($timeout) {
         return function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
             iElement.autocomplete({
                 source: scope[iAttrs.uiItems],
                 elect: function() {
                     $timeout(function() {
                         iElement.trigger('input');
                     }, 0);
                 }
             });
         };
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the `{{selected}}` $scope variable has not been defined.

Second, your controller has not been defined. Thats why it got undefined.

`var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);`

`myApp.controller('DefaultController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.greeting = 'Hola!';
}]);`

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller

Third, based on performance for your website, put your Javascript in an external file and load it after the DOM has been loaded. Except if you need your Javascript available before the website has completely rendered. Otherwise it blocks your webpage loading.

Answer (score 0):

Controller should be declare as below:

```
var app = angular.module("app", ["ngRoute", ...]);    

app.controller("DefaultCtrl", ["$scope", ..., function($scope){
      $scope.names = ["john"];
}]);
```